# The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null. The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have hosted by WCF service on a URL (http://192.168.2.131:8089/). Now, I'm trying to invoke the WCF service from a Windows form, but I'm getting this error:

> The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.

Here is the win form C# code:

```
var binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.2.131:8089/");

InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new Form1());

var cFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IPubSubService>(context);

IPubSubService client = null;
client = cFactory.CreateChannel();
client.SendNotification();
```

`client = cFactory.CreateChannel();` is throwing the error.

Here is the `system.serviceModel` config for the WCF service and the Winforms `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
     <service name="PubSubServiceLib.PubSubService">
        <endpoint 
            address="" 
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
            contract="PubSubServiceLib.IPubSubService">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
           <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://192.168.2.131:8089/"/>
           </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
         <binding receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" 
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="02:00:00"/>
         </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You create the endpoint, but you never assign it to anything.

Comment: can you inspect `cFactory ` to see if the `endpoint` was set before creating the channel?

Comment: @Tim thnks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the overload of [DuplexChannelFactory(InstanceContext, Binding, EndpointAddress)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574946%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes the binding and endpoint, so the factory will have the required components.

Updated code:

```
var binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.2.131:8089/");
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new Form1());
var cFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IPubSubService>(context, binding, endpoint);
```

This will assign the binding and endpoint address to the `DuplexChannelFactory`.

Also make sure your `Form1` implements the callback contract.